# In what unit does the distance() function return ? i.e meters/feet/inches/kms/miles,etc and, is there inaccuracy in using geoCode in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, geocoding

[In what unit does the distance() function return ? i.e meters/feet/inches/kms/miles,etc and, is there inaccuracy in using geoCode in Neo4j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Omqc.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by 'inaccuracy in using geoCode in Neo4j'? Inaccuracy in doing anything with points and distances?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/spatial/#functions-distance) indicates that calling `distance` on two lat/long arguments gives the result in metres.

> If the points are in the WGS-84 CRS (3D), then the units of the returned distance will be meters.

The result will always be an approximation, because it assumes a spherical Earth - the real Earth is slightly ellipoidal. [This answer would suggest a likely max error of about 0.3%](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25580) with the sort of calculation that Neo4j (and most other databases) use.